# Write ADODB Stream data to pdftk's stdin

Tags: vba, ms-access, stream, stdin, adodb

Using VBA for Access: What I need to do is get BLOB data to a "textstream" and send that to pdftk's stdin. Here is what I have so far:

```
With objStream
    .Type = adTypeBinary
    .Open
    .Write Rst.Fields("lngBLOB").Value
    .Position = 0
    .Type = adTypeText
    .CharSet = "us-ascii"
End With

txtStrContract = objStream.ReadText

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = objShell.Exec("CMD /K")

With oExec
    .StdIn.WriteLine "pdftk - fill_form """ & strTempXFDF & """ output """ & strFilledPDF & """"

        .StdIn.Write txtStrContract

    Debug.Print .StdErr.ReadAll()
    Debug.Print .StdOut.ReadAll()

End With
```

The only problem is, I don't get any errors but my merged pdf file doesn't get created either.
I have checked that the file will merge successfully if I extract both files and merge them manually via the command line

I have searched until I felt like I was losing my mind!